# How see test reports after maven build in Intelij Idea?

Tags: maven, testing, intellij-idea

I have run maven goal from Intellij Idea, build was been completed, tests were passed. How to browse with Intellij Idea all test reports which are stored in *taget* folders?

Answer (score 1):

There is [maven test support plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7446?pr=) for Intellij Idea. Just select maven subproject folder in project tree, press left mouse button and select "Show test results". :)